# can we override outlook sender name in html email?

Tags: php, mailto

I have an html email newsletter sent monthly to customers. I've added a forward to friend link in the layout having

```
href="mailto:%20?subject=SUBJECT &body=TEXT">
```

Now when I click the button, it opens "outlook new Email" page.
When I send the email to myself(testing), I get the email with the sender name as my name which is the account name in my outlook email account.
So my question is can we override this sender name and choose one to appear bydefault in this case?

Comment: Send it using the internal PHP mail functions, not a mailto: reference on your own machine.. then you can send it as anything such as "<The one and only>BestUser@mydomain.com" as its your domain it wont check who you send it from

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything you can do with an href mail to link.

http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks11.htm

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with "mailto:" link.

You may need to create some small "contact me" website with contact form.